# iPhones models currently in circulation

Tags: iphone, mobile

Does Apple provide data about iPhone models currently in circulation? I can only find data about iOS versions. I'm about to port a game from Android and I'm wondering if I need to worry about any models lower than the iPhone4, most specifically the 3GS? If they're less than a couple of % of the current market share then I won't worry about it.

Do Apple, or anyone else provide this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that the iPhone 3GS is the most recent iPhone model which cannot run iOS 7.

Apple provide information on OS version (but not device) here:

https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/

As at August 24 2014, the splits were:

iOS 7: 91%
iOS 6: 8%
pre-iOS 6: 1%

That gives a cap of 8% of total iOS users using the iPhone 3GS. In practice, it will be much less than that, because there are also some iPads and iPod touches which don't support iOS7, plus people on later devices who have chosen not to upgrade.

Stats from one of our own popular apps which is run almost exclusively on iPhone show that <3% of users are on iOS 6 or earlier with a screen size of 320x480 (and therefore no more than 3% of users are on iPhone 3GS).

As regards porting or creating a new app, I would need a very strong motivation to support iOS 6. My default position would be iOS 7.1 or above.

Comment: Surely phone/tablet models is data they could easily provide. I can't think why they wouldn't want. I'm sure it's a carefully thought out part of their master plan though.

Comment: They charge for devices; they don't charge for OS updates. Consequently model split is commercially sensitive data, whereas OS version isn't.